# Display image from query output HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

In a given database using MYSQL, I am storing image file paths to be displayed. I retrieve the path using a query. The returned value is stored in a 'var' type variable. How can I use this as input to the `img` `src` attribute to display the image?

For Example:

```
var x = "http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif";
<img src=x>
```

I am not able to use the above, so is there a way to display the image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be more clear, how do you get the variable? Which server programming language are you using or do you want to use?

Comment: Do you want to display image using javascript?

Comment: *Why* are you "*not able to use the above*"? Arbitrary requirements usually imply a school, or academic, assignment; which isn't forbidden but you need to explain, in this case, what you *have* tried, and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new image in Javascript using the `Image` Constructor.

```js
var x = "http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif";
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = x;
document.body.appendChild(myImage);
```

Comment: Yeah it worked great ! Didn't know abt the .src part!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
var x = "http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif";
document.getElementById("YOUR_IMAGR_ID").src = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the image tag dynamically in javascript 
**Javascript Code**

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif");
    x.setAttribute("width", "304");
    x.setAttribute("width", "228");
    x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" >Display Image</button>
</body>
```

Please check the [demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/fpOErREbmaYToh1nU1iH/)

Comment: @DavidThomas have you clicked on demo.. It will redirect you to the code link and demo

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```js
function set(){
    document.getElementById('tmp').style.visibility = "visible";
     var x = "http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif";
     document.getElementById("tmp").src = x;
 }
```

```html
<img src="" id="tmp" style="visibility:hidden">
<input type="button" onclick="set();" value="Click Me!">
```